Streamlines due to equal and opposite rectilinear vortices in infinite liquid
The question goes:
When an infinite liquid contains two parallel, equal and opposite rectilinear vortices at a distance 2b, prove that the streamlines relative to the vertices are given by the equation:
$$\log[\frac{x^2 + (y-b)^2}{x^2 + (y+b)^2}]+\frac{y}{b}=C$$
the origin is the middle point of the join, which is taken along Y-axis and C is an arbitrary constant.
The solution in the book goes like this:
The vortex system is moving with uniform velocity $\frac{k}{2\pi}$ perpendicular to the line joining the vortices. So we superpose a velocity $\frac{-k}{4\pi b}$ to put the vortex system at rest.
The stream function of the superposed system is then given by:
$$-\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial y}=-\frac{k}{4\pi b}$$
And the complex potential due to the above is:
$$w_1 = \frac{kz}{4\pi b}$$
The rest of the solution is easy to understand but can you help me understand why we introduced this velocity, how we came up with the superposed velocity, and how we got to $w_1$
